# Is there a way to keep a word sized immediate in a 32bit register instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, nasm

Assume the following x86-32 instruction:

```
add ebx,1
```

There are (at least) two ways to assemble this opcode:

```
81 c3 01 00 00 00
```

or

```
83 c3 01
```

The first keeps 1 as a 4 bytes dword
the second keeps 1 as a byte

Is there an instruction that keeps 1 as 2 bytes?
If no why?

Comment: My favorite here is `inc ebx`, or load the constant into another reg if I'm going to use it a lot and then `add ebx,reg`.

Comment: why not?  Because it would require too many extra opcodes or prefixes.  As early as 386, Intel realized that leaving room for future extensions was potentially important, and didn't fill up the coding space.  If the opcode or prefix is one byte longer for a hypothetical `add r/m32, imm16`, it only ends up saving one byte instead of two.  Immediates that fit in 16 bits but not 8 are quite rare: most numbers are either small or pointers, so it wouldn't be useful enough to justify the cost.

Answer (score 12):

You have stumbled upon a quirk of the x86 instruction set.  Intel included a group of instructions under the stem `83`, whose first operand is of type `Ev`, and whose second operand is an immediate byte that is interpreted as being the same size as the `Ev` operand.  So for `83 c3 01`, the `01` is interpreted as a 32-bit value; for `66 83 c3 01`, the 01 is interpreted as a 16-bit value (and the destination is the 16-bit `ax` register).  The `push` mnemonic coded under the stem `6A` behaves in the same way with respect to the size of its single operand.

The broader answer to your question is no, there is no encoding where a 16-bit constant is interpreted as a 32-bit one.

Source:  I wrote a disassembler.

Comment: You might want to explain what `Ev` means (in case OP doesn't know that it means general-purpose register or effective address).

Answer (score 0):

66 81 C3 01 00 ("add bx, 01" when in 32-bit mode) might be considered an example of it.

There is no such example that does not require an override because there isn't a need for it.  The reason why the first example requires four bytes is so that it can span the entire 4Gb range.  The second one uses only one byte because it is limited to +/-128 (256 values total).  By using an override, we can restrict the first example to 64kb, but really it's not one byte in two, it's still two bytes.

Comment: What codings would be available for `LEA EBX,[EBX+nn]`?  That wouldn't set flags, so it wouldn't be an exact replacement, but for values between 128 and 16777215 it might be more compact than ADD.

Comment: @supercat The set of available values is the same - you can use the 32-bit immediate for 4Gb values, or a one-byte value for sign-extended values.  You can also use an override 67h to change [EBX...] to [BX...] for 64kb values.  The encoding size is the same for ADD and LEA for your EBX example.

Comment: I'd thought that form had an intermediate size.  Guess not.  I don't think the 16-bit form is at all equivalent, though, since if EBX is e.g. 0x12345000, adding 0xBFFF to BX would make EBX equal 0x1234FFFF, but adding 0xC000 would make EBX equal 0x12340000.

Comment: @supercat that's not how the 16-bit version works.  It will zero-extend the value, so ebx=0x12345000 / lea ebx,[bx+1234] -> ebx 0x00006234 because it's performing ebx=bx+1234.

Comment: Thinking about it, aren't there actually three different "16-bit" versions depending upon whether the address, destination operand, or both is modified?  In any case, none of them are going to correctly handle carry out of bit 15.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to use small integers in programming - regardless of the destination size. The benefit is reduced instruction encoding. Many instruction support this: IMUL, ADD, ADC, SUB, SBB, AND, CMP, etc... Also, the addressing mode supports a byte size sign-extended offset to help reduce code size.

As to the why not: I would gather the added savings is minimal in comparison to the savings of the byte encoding. The ENTER instruction does use a 16-bit immediate, but it is unsigned and fixed to updating register RSP/ESP/SP.